# Regularity of eigenfunctions of an ordinary differential operator

Tags: operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, differential-operators

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $T:D(T)\subseteq L^2(I) \to L^2(I)$ a differential operator given by
$$(Tf)(x):= \sum_{j=0}^n a_j(x)f^{(j)}(x), \quad f\in D(T), \ x \in I,$$
where the derivatives are understood in the weak sense. Under what conditions in $a_j(x)$ can we say that $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ iff there exists a non-trivial classic solution $f \in D(T)$ of $(T-\lambda)f=0$?. Do you know any reference for that?

Comment: Don't you want boundary conditions before stating the eigenvalue problem? When $a_j$ are smooth, then for **every** $\lambda$ there exists a two dimensional space of classical solutions to the equation $(T-\lambda )f = 0$, if you don't prescribe the boundary condition.

Comment: @WillieWong: Isn't it actually $n$-dimensional (rather than $2$-dimensional)? In any case, the solution will, in general, be as regular as the worst of the terms $a_j f^{(j)}$. If, for example, all $a_j$ will be merely bounded Borel functions, then $f$ need not even have a classical $n$-th derivative. Just consider all $a_j$ equal to zero, except $a_n = n! \mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}$, so that $f(x) = x^n \mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}$ solves $T f = 0$ in the weak sense.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: yes, of course you are right.